# catkin_make unable to find actionlib in its original install location

Tags: catkin-make, catkin, ros-kinetic, actionlib

[image: Rosanswers logo]

It seems as though it is looking for actionlib in one of our catkin workspaces. It was installed to /opt/ros/kinetic/share/actionlib.
Is there a way to correct how catkin finds it? Is there another issue causing this?

```
CMake Error at /home/user/catkin_ws/devel/share/actionlib/cmake/actionlibConfig.cmake:113 (message):
  Project 'actionlib' specifies
  '/home/user/catkin_ws/src/actionlib/actionlib/include' as an include dir,
  which is not found.  It does neither exist as an absolute directory nor in
  '/home/user/catkin_ws/src/actionlib/actionlib//home/user/catkin_ws/src/actionlib/actionlib/include'.
  Check the issue tracker 'https://github.com/ros/actionlib/issues' and
  consider creating a ticket if the problem has not been reported yet.
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  /opt/ros/kinetic/share/tf2_ros/cmake/tf2_rosConfig.cmake:197 (find_package)
  /opt/ros/kinetic/share/tf/cmake/tfConfig.cmake:197 (find_package)
  /opt/ros/kinetic/share/amcl/cmake/amclConfig.cmake:197 (find_package)
  /opt/ros/kinetic/share/catkin/cmake/catkinConfig.cmake:76 (find_package)
  basic_swarm/CMakeLists.txt:10 (find_package)
```

Edit: There are two workspaces. I'm working in workspace 2, I removed catkin_ws and now ws 2 makes fine. My new question is why did this happen to begin with?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/380686/catkin_make-unable-to-find-actionlib-in-its-original-install-location/) by [cwillia109](https://answers.ros.org/users/51647/cwillia109/) on ROS Answers with karma: 49 on 2021-06-20

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

It's hard to debug this after you've already fixed the issue. But I guess you did something along the following lines:

1. You created `catkin_ws` and added `source path/to/catkin_ws/devel/setup.bash` to your `.bashrc`
2. You cloned `actionlib` into `catkin_ws` and built it
3. You created `ws2`, creating an overlay over `catkin_ws` through [workspace chaining](http://wiki.ros.org/catkin/Tutorials/workspace_overlaying#Chaining_catkin_workspaces), as this had been source'd through your `.bashrc`
4. You added `source path/to/ws2/devel/setup.bash` to your `.bashrc`
5. You deleted `actionlib` from `catkin_ws`, but did not run a clean build. thus, the cmake artifacts remained, pointing to the now non-existing location
6. When building `ws2`, you are presented with the above problem. By deleting `catkin_ws` and thus the cmake artifcats etc present in that workspace, you fixed everything.

If you still have both `source` commands in your `.bashrc` you should see an error about not finding `catkin_ws/devel/setup.bash` every time you open a new terminal. Note that the "last command wins" when sourcing ROS workspaces (built with catkin). Thus, all previous ones don't take effect.

This is one of the reasons why I personally advocate to never put your `source`-command into the `.bashrc` execpt for when you are only working with a single workspace ever (which, as soon as you start to work in larger or more advanced projects, you'll probably not do anymore).

---

Originally posted by [mgruhler](https://answers.ros.org/users/2647/mgruhler/) with karma: 12390 on 2021-06-21

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [cwillia109](https://answers.ros.org/users/51647/cwillia109/) on 2021-06-28**:
I'm not the only one using the machine, so something along those lines might have happened thank you. Accepted as an answer for search engine's sake.

**Comment by [mgruhler](https://answers.ros.org/users/2647/mgruhler/) on 2021-06-29**:
To prevent this from happening again I suggest then the following:

1. use dedicated user accounts ;-)
2. if dedicated user accounts are not possible: whenever you create a new workspace, first `source /opt/ros/<DISTRO>/setup.bash`, create your workspace, and manually source this workspace in each new terminal. This should prevent you from from accidentally chaining workspaces again